# Is there a postgresql equivalent to mysql's SET @@default_storage_engine = 'MyISAM';

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a MYSQL script I am trying to convert to Postgres and there are a number of sections that are setting the default engine or changing the engine between InnoDB and MyISAM. Is there any equivalent in Postgres for changing the default engine between the 2?

The MYSQL line is:

```
SET @@default_storage_engine = 'MyISAM';
```

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Why do you think there is storage engine in PostgreSQL?

Comment: I didn't think there was but I just wanted to triple check in case I missed something somewhere or in the event that it was called something completely different. I'm not that familiar with PostgreSQL

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for this configuration option in PostgreSQL, because PostgreSQL does not have pluggable storage engines. All tables will use the same storage engine, which is the only one PostgreSQL supports.

Therefore as you port your script to PostgreSQL, you may simply delete that line.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent in PostgreSQL is `default_table_access_method`.  However, it supports neither 'InnoDB' nor 'MyISAM'.  The only access method that comes with PostgreSQL (currently) is 'heap'. Other ones may be installable as 3rd party plugins.